# How can I get even columns in my latex table?

Tags: tables, overleaf

[image]

How can I fix my code? My columns don't have the same width

```
    \begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|cc|ccc|}
\hline
      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Test2: Running application}        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Test1: Running application}                                    \\ \hline
Group & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{G} & $\chi^2$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{water} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{tea} & soda \\ \hline
1     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2}     & 0   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2}   & 1    \\ \hline
2     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3}     & 1   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2}   & 1    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{5}{w{c}{5em}|}}
    \hline
      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Test2: Running application}        
                                & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Test1: Running application}                                  \\ 
      \hline
Group &     G   &   $\chi^2$    &   water   & tea   & soda  \\ \hline
1     &     2   &   0           &   3       &   2   &   1   \\ \hline
2     &     3   &   1           &   2       &   2   &   1   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

However, I would rather redesign table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{c *{5}{w{c}{3.2em}} }
    \toprule
      & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Running application}    \\
    \cmidrule{2-6}       
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Test 1}
                        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Test1}   \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3}   \cmidrule(l){4-6}
Group & G   & $\chi^2$  & water & tea   & soda  \\ 
    \midrule
1     & 2   & 0         & 3     & 2     & 1     \\ 
2     & 3   & 1         & 2     & 2     & 1     \\ 
    \bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much